# What could be the lead to prove $||X||_2 \leq ||X||_F \leq \sqrt{rank(X)}||X||_2$?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

In the above statement, $||X||_2$ = $L_2$ norm of X and $||X||_F$ = $Frobenius$ norm of X.
It appears to me that the $L2$ norm of X and $Frobenius$ norm of X are the same. How should i proceed to prove the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the singular values $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$ of $X$, where $r=\mathrm{rank}(X)$, such that $\sigma_1\geq\cdots\geq\sigma_r>0$ and the expressions
$$
\|X\|_2=\sigma_1,\quad \|X\|_F=\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_r^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, this way looks promising. Frankly, I am all drowned in all sorts of correlations between matrix terminologies. Do you mind suggesting any path ways for me to look into the equivalence of matrix norms with singular values or say just eigen values?

Comment: Since the singular values of $X$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $X^*X$, it can of course be explained in terms of eigenvalues as well. The crucial points are to note that: 1) $\|X\|_2=\sqrt{\rho(X^*X)}$, 2) $X^*X$ is positive definite (has real positive eigenvalues), 4) rank of $X$ is the same as that of $X^*X$ and is equal to the number of nonzero eigenvalues of $X^*X$, 5) $\|X\|_F=\sqrt{\mathrm{trace}(X^*X)}$, 6) trace is basis-independent ($\mathrm{trace}(X^*X)$ is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues of $X^*X$).